# Provisioning raspbery pi sdcard

Tags: ansible, provisioning

I was searching for a tool suitable for provisioning sdcard for raspberry pi.

I've successfully managed to implement most of it using Ansible playbook. Need only some time for last polishing.

Process looks like this:

1. Format sdcard
2. Mount sdcard in temporary directory
3. Debootstrap sid
4. Chroot
5. Finish configuration

It seems to work well for now, but I'm a bit worried that it is not in the scope of Ansible. Is there any more suitable tool for this task?

Comment: Hi ! I can understand the gist of the question - perhaps you feel uncertain about the general applicability of an approach - but posed in this way, it is quite difficult to provide an actual answer. The question "is this approach suitable" does not have a yes/no answer, but depends on the context. Can you help us understand your situation - how often are you doing this? Is it something only _you_ are doing, or is it part of a service offered to others? Do you need to run it in different situations? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you're previsioning your raspberry pi SD cards then you would probably be best using something like packer to build the actual image (you can use ansible as the provisioner for packer if you are really keen) then once you have your pi image, burn it onto the SD card.

If you need to make subsequent configuration changes them that would be where ansible fits most neatly in managing the ongoing configuration of the pi's